# How i can solve the error "The nvcc binary could not be ' OSError: The nvcc binary could not be located in your $PATH" py-faster-rcnn

Tags: python, cmd, makefile, image-recognition, faster-rcnn

I am trying to run and implement [py-faster-rcnn from GitHub](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn), using Python. I already clone the repository, but when I try to run `make` in `cmd`, as written within the installation instructions, it outputs the following error:

```
C:\Users\Yaman\py-faster-rcnn\lib>make python setup.py build_ext
--inplace Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 58, in <module>
    CUDA = locate_cuda()   File "setup.py", line 46, in locate_cuda
    raise EnvironmentError('The nvcc binary could not be ' OSError: The nvcc binary could not be located in your $PATH. Either add it to
your path, or set $CUDAHOME make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Although I got the following when I tried `nvcc --version`:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA
Corporation Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:32:27_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

Can anyone give suggestion how I could solve this error? I am using Windows 10.

Here's a snapshot of my System environment variables:

[image: Snapshot of the system environment variables]